# Late estimated quarterly payment because state failed to act on ACH authorization

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, estimated-taxes, ach, pennsylvania

In October I submitted payment for Q3 taxes to PA and received a confirmation number for my payment. But they failed to act on that authorization until January, when they must have noticed it at the same time I filed my Q4 estimated payment (I was initially confused at seeing two PA charges out of my bank account this month). So now my Q3 payment is on the books as 3 months late.

Do I have any recourse or legal standing to ask the state to forgive the late payment?

Comment: What books is it showing as late on?  Is Pennsylvania charging you late fees, or does it just look funny in your Quicken?

Comment: My books have it 'on time' because I authorized the ACH on time. The bank's books  show the payment occurring late, because the actual transfer of funds occurred late, unless there's a way to get the bank to provide a record of when I made the ACH authorization. I can't see the state's books. They have not charged me late fees yet; I'm just concerned that they will. Heh well I should just calm down and see what happens first.

Answer (score 3):

If you filed your forms by the deadline, and provided them an instrument for paying what was due; then you are fine.

In the days when you sent in these forms by mail, the only requirement was that it had to be postmarked by the due date. The tax agency could take days or weeks to cash that check. It was completely out of your control.

The same is true today. The tax authority determines when they withdraw the the money. They should be quick to get what they are owed, and to minimize the chances that an account has insufficient funds.

Your receipt with the date and time is proof of filing.  If they want to charge you for a late payment then file an appeal.